# A more stable alternative Meta Tracker Linux search system

Tags: search, metadata, desktop-search

An indexed search system is a very convenient tool for many computer-related tasks.

I have been using [Meta Tracker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MetaTracker_%28software%29) for a few years on Ubuntu and have met a lot of issues:

- sometimes the Tracker icon just disappears from the notification area;
- sometimes the settings, that I provide to the Tracker are not applied: the Tracker can start indexing when I am on battery or it can forget to index some custom directories;
- sometimes it just does not find files which am sure are in the file system.

So, my question is: Is there any Linux (Gnome/KDE, does not matter) desktop search system that does not have all the above mentioned problems and is stable at work?

Edit: Tracker's nice feature that allows to tag files (integrates with Nautilus) is not stable as well. A tag-based search on a desktop system could be very useful though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your question prompted me to look around for a program and I discovered that I already had `Recoll` installed. Wish I had known that, would have been using it. So, I have no real experience with it yet, but it seems to work OK.

Link to product:  [Recoil, Full Text Search for Linux](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/)

> It is based on the very strong Xapian search engine library, for which
>   it provides a powerful text extraction layer and a complete, yet easy
>   to use, Qt graphical interface.
>
> Recoll is free, open source, and licensed under the GPL. The current
>   version is 1.16.2 (Release notes).

Comment: Thanks, it works really fast! I wish I had it integrated into the OS.